# Tabs app is suddenly closing

Tags: android

im having a little problem with my app.  So first off my app is just a simple tabs app that displays a different webview on each page.  Currently I only have the home page as webview.  Im not getting any type of errors but when I try to open and run my app it suddenly closes.  Any suggestions on how I can finally make this app work correctly

Thank you

```
Arrowactivity.java

package app.tabsample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * @author Adil Soomro
 *
 */
public class ArrowsActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.arrowspage);      
    }
}


Optionsactivity.java

package app.tabsample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * @author Adil Soomro
 *
 */
public class OptionsActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.optionspage);


    }
}

Tabsample.java


package app.tabsample;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * @author Adil Soomro
 *
 */
public class TabSample extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setTabs() ;
    }
    private void setTabs()
    {
        addTab("Home", R.drawable.tab_home, WebViewActivity.class);
        addTab("News", R.drawable.tab_search, OptionsActivity.class);

        addTab("Workouts", R.drawable.tab_home, ArrowsActivity.class);
        addTab("Nutrition", R.drawable.tab_search, OptionsActivity.class);
    }

    private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
    {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
        TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(labelId);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}


webViewactivity.java

package app.tabsample;

import app.tabsample.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.weblayout);

        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);



        wv.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/repmax.html");




    }

    private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return(true);
        }
    }

}

arrowspage.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Welcome"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:textSize="20sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>


weblayout.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.webkit.WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </android.webkit.WebView>

</RelativeLayout>



main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"  />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost> 


tab_indicator.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="55dip"    
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"

    /> 

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
    />    
</RelativeLayout>

optionspage.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <EditText android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:hint="Search Text"/>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:text="Search"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post Logcat output

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and I was able to see the tabs with the `WebView`. Since you have not posted your `logcat` it is going to be really hard to guess the problem.

Check if you have added your Activity's - `TabSample`, `WebViewActivity`, `OptionsActivity`, `ArrowsActivity` - to the manifest.

```
<activity
    android:name="app.tabsample.TabSample"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity 
    android:name="app.tabsample.WebViewActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
<activity 
    android:name="app.tabsample.OptionsActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" /> 
<activity 
    android:name="app.tabsample.ArrowsActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

If this does not fix your problem, then please update your question by adding the `logcat` errors.